How to set precision of a label through python console in QGIS
I want to do a raster calculation through a python script and I want to apply some changes: for example I want to disply the new layer with Quantile mode and 35 number of classes. But also I want to have 4 decimals as precision of the label but I can't find something that makes me do that.
# Load the raster layer
lyr1 = QgsRasterLayer(r'C:\Users\fisico\Desktop\Aureli\II_MODULO_CTA\foto_cemento_completa\DJI_20240131155537_0037.JPG')

# Define the output file path
output = r'C:\Users\fisico\Desktop\Aureli\II_MODULO_CTA\foto_cemento_raster_calculator\output_prova_raster_2.tif'

# Prepare raster calculator entries for the red and green bands
entries = []

# Entry for the red band (band 1)
red = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
red.ref = 'red@1'
red.raster = lyr1
red.bandNumber = 1
entries.append(red)

# Entry for the green band (band 2)
green = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
green.ref = 'green@2'
green.raster = lyr1
green.bandNumber = 2
entries.append(green)

# Create the formula for the calculation
formula = '(green@2 - red@1) / (green@2 + red@1)'

# Set up and run the raster calculator
calc = QgsRasterCalculator(formula, output, 'GTiff', lyr1.extent(), lyr1.width(), lyr1.height(), entries)
calc.processCalculation()

output_layer = QgsRasterLayer(output, 'Output Prova Raster')
if output_layer.isValid():
        
    # Create a color ramp shader
    shader = QgsRasterShader()
    color_ramp_shader = QgsColorRampShader()
    color_ramp_shader.setClassificationMode(QgsColorRampShader.Quantile)
  
    color_ramp_shader.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated)
        
    shader.setRasterShaderFunction(color_ramp_shader)
    
    # Classify the color ramp with 35 classes
    provider = output_layer.dataProvider()
    extent = output_layer.extent()
    color_ramp_shader.classifyColorRamp(35, 1, extent, provider)
    

    # Apply the single band pseudo color renderer
    renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(output_layer.dataProvider(), 1, shader)
    
    
    output_layer.setRenderer(renderer)

    # Add the layer to the project
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(output_layer)
else:
    print("Il nuovo raster layer non è valido")

I tried to search in the library but I don't find anything that makes me do that.
Thanks in advance
